# Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use - Error in Netbeans only

Tags: java, netbeans

On my machine, the following code compiles within Eclipse but throws an exception within Netbeans.  The error message says "Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use".

What is the proper configuration within Netbeans to make this code compile?  It seems like the problem has to do with the fact that I have two main functions.  If I start running either one of the apps, the second will fail to start, throwing the exception posted above.

Server.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Server myServ = new Server();
        myServ.run();

    }

    public void run() throws Exception {

        ServerSocket mySS = new ServerSocket(9999);
        Socket SS_accept = mySS.accept();

        InputStreamReader mySR = new InputStreamReader(SS_accept.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader myBR = new BufferedReader(mySR);

        String temp = myBR.readLine();
        System.out.println(temp);

    }

}
```

Client.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Client myCli = new Client();
        myCli.run();

    }

    public void run() throws Exception {

        Socket mySkt = new Socket("localhost", 9999);
        PrintStream myPS = new PrintStream(mySkt.getOutputStream());

        myPS.println("Hello server");

    }

}
```

Comment: Make sure you run the `Server` class in your Eclipse or in your NetBeans only. Otherwise, if you want to run both servers, change the port number.

Comment: Where am I supposed to run the Client app if not within Netbeans?  Also, what do you mean by both servers?  There is only one Server app.

Comment: Which class are you running on eclipse and which one on netbeans?

Comment: No no...I was trying to develop it in Netbeans (both classes).  When I ran into trouble, I flipped over to Eclipse, developed both classes there, and I have no problems.  So my problem is...within Netbeans, how can I successfully run both classes/apps?  If you look at the code, once the server app is running, the client app can startup and interact with the server app using sockets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to achieve what I want is to right-click on the particular class (ex. `Server.java`) that I want to run and select "Run this file".  This enables me to run only the Server app.  Then, do the same process for the other file, `Client.java`.

However, Netbeans is somewhat confusing/deceiving in this particular circumstance.  What Netbeans does is it runs the `Server` process, but labels that process as the name of the project (ex. MyTestNetworkingProject) and puts a run number on it, thus giving us `MyTestNetworkingProject run #1` (it actually leaves out the #1 on the first process).  Then, if I go to the Client.java file and select "Run this file", it generates a second process, `MyTestNetworkingProject run #2`.  It then generates a second results window down at the bottom of the screen, as it generates these in new tabs as new processes get created.

Because of the nature of my specific code, what I wanted to see in my results window to confirm that my application was working was I wanted to observe the Server.java results window (which in this case is `MyTestNetworkingProject run #1`).  Given my exact sequence of steps outlined above of running the different files, run #2 is the last run process and thus the tab on top, covering the run #1 tab.  I can click on run #1 and see the results I was hoping to see in the console ("Hello server"), but I just have to know/remember that `MyTestNetworkingProject run #1` represents the Server app and not the Client app.

Uncool, IMO.

Comment: Something similar occurs in Eclipse console when you run 2 or more classes with `public static void main(String[] args)`. I don't think this is an IDE problem.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is due to the fact that you left one instance of your server running and then started another one.

Comment: I figured out how to manually kill the processes in Netbeans, so I do not think that is it.  In fact, I even closed the IDE completely and restarted.  Perhaps I am not starting my apps correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If you write this in Windows OS,you can use "netstat -nao" to see which process use the 9999 port.If it is some unimportant process,you can kill this process.Otherwise you can change the port of the pragram.

Comment: I have tried various port numbers with the same result.  Also, my OS is linux.

Answer (score 0):

I change the port address and it work for me in the Neat Beans IDE . This problem will come if we used the same port address for other one times . so to fix this error you have to change the port address and I am sure it will work

Answer (score -1):

Server.java

```
public class SocServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(5001);
            Socket client = server.accept();
            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            os.writeBytes("Hello Sockets\n");
            client.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Client.java

```
public class SocClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Socket socClient = new Socket("localhost", 5001);
            InputStream is = socClient.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String receivedData = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Received Data: " + receivedData);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

refer above code and it works for me..

Comment: It may indeed work for you, despite the obvious socket leak, but it doesn't answer the question in any way.

Answer (score -1):

I did try the method `catch` and solved the problem.